# Python len() doesn't work but __len__ does with class holding a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, oop

Here is my minimal working example:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def __len__(self):
        return np.array([len(self.arr)]).astype(np.int8)

    def size():
        return self.__len__()



class Two(One):
    def __init__(self, arr):
        super().__init__(arr)

# Create an instance of the second class
a = Two(np.array([0.4, 0.6]))
# I can call a.size()
print("a.size(): ", a.size())
# I can call a.__len__()
print("a.__len__(): ", a.__len__())
# I cannot call len(a)
print("len(a): ", len(a))
```

So basically I have class `One` that has a constructor `__init__` , a method `__len__` that should implement `len(One)` and finally another method called `size` that simply calls the `__len__` method.

As you can see, I can easily call `a.__len__()` and `a.size()` but I can't call `len(a)`, because I get:

```
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

I tried debugging and everything goes fine till the end, except that I just get an error..

Comment: [`__len__()` should return a single integer](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__). what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Well if you want to have a look, I am working on this project on GitHub (https://github.com/MauroCE/PythonBRMLtoolbox/tree/master). Basically, I want to implement a Probability Table class. This class holds a numpy array as an attribute. All I want to do, is that if you instantiate the class `Array` as a = Array([1, 2], np.array([[0.4, 0.6],[0.3, 0.7]]))` then by calling `len(a)` you'll get the shape of `np.array([[0.4, 0.6],[0.3, 0.7]])`

Comment: Why don't you implement a `.shape` property then?

Comment: You cannot do that. `len` enforces that it returns an `int`. If it does not return an `int`, then the interpreter calls the `__index__` method of the object (if one exists). The error you see is because numpy array `__index__` method refuses to convert a 1-element array to an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written in comments, you will find [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__len__) that:

> `__len__()` should return the length of the object, an integer >= 0.

It is not clear what you expect to be returned by `len()`, but this code works well for example:

```
class One:
    def __init__(self, arr):
        self.arr = arr

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.arr)

    def size(self):
        return self.__len__()
```

Comment: Basically I want to return `arr.shape`. But instead of returning a tuple, I want to return a numpy array

Comment: If you want an array shape, implement your own method. Don't abuse (and violate) the `__len__` protocol.

Comment: You can **not** use `len()` to return anything different from a positive integer. Nothing more to say...

Comment: Makes sense, although this means I'll have to re-factor some of my code..